# Want to compare Timestamps in Drools

Tags: java, timestamp, drools

I am to receive a timestamp value and want to check it agains the current timeStamp value to make sure that the value I am getting is less of before the current time stamp.

the value being sent is in this format *2022-05-13 17:52:07*

```
rule "effectiveTimestamp is in past "
when
    $retail: DroolsDTO(pricingExecutionDetails.effectiveTimestamp != null &&
    pricingExecutionDetails.effectiveTimestamp.compareTo(java.sql.Timestamp.from(Instant.now())) >= 0 )
    $locale: Locale()
then
    modify($retail) {
        setIsValid(false),
        getViolationList().add(source.getMessage(config.pastEffectiveTimestamp, null, $locale))
    }
end
```

I think the
java.sql.Timestamp.from(Instant.now()) has milli seconds attached to it - ex:
2022-05-13 19:14:21.371. am not sure if this matters when comparing

this is how the effectiveTimestamp field is defined in the DTO

```
  @JsonProperty("effectiveTimestamp")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
  private Instant effectiveTimestamp;
```

this is the error I m getting

> [2m2022-05-13 15:40:28.586[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m69147[0;39m
> [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m
> [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m
> Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Text '2021-11-30 17:52:07' could not be parsed at
> index 10; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2021-11-30
> 17:52:07' could not be parsed at index 10 (through reference chain:
> com.sams.pricing.rulesexecutor.dto.DroolsDTO["priceExecutionDetails"]->com.sams.pricing.execution.common.dto.PricingExecutionDetailsDTO["effectiveTimestamp"])]

(also I may have to change the >= 0 to < but thats just a side note still getting this parsing error )

Comment: This has nothing to do with Drools. The error indicates that you're not deserializing your input properly. It's getting stuck at your Spring REST(I presume) interface where you deserialize the input. Probably there's something wrong with that CustomDeserializer class of yours.

Comment: thanks - you were right, data was not being sent properly